# UK Home and Mobile Phone Number validation

Tags: php

I am currently using the validation

```
$pattern = "/^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/";
```

However although this accepted mobile numbers, such as 07515674321, but won't accept a home phone number, such as 01623749983. Does anybody have the correct validation?

Comment: you can find the valid formats of phone numbers here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom#Format, this is excluding special text numbers etc

Comment: Try this?: `^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$`

Comment: @PRNDLDevelopmentStudios using that it wouldn't let me save my document due to formatting "some characters can't be mapped to MacRoman"

Comment: For completeness, here is the official reference http://stakeholders.ofcom.org.uk/telecoms/numbering/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work with both Mobile Numbers and Home Phone Numbers

```
/^((\(?0\d{4}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|(\(?0\d{3}\)?\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|(\(?0\d{2}\)?\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$/
```